# Почему не пропадают значения после применения .dropna()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

У меня в фрейме данных есть колонки с нулевыми значениями. Когда я делаю:

```
df.isnull().sum()
```

в списке колонок я наблюдаю следущее:

```
open_acc                  0
pub_rec                   0
pub_rec_bankruptcies    535
purpose                   0
revol_bal                 0
revol_util              276
sub_grade                 0
term                      0
```

Нужно убрать эти ряды, таким образом я делаю:

```
df['revol_util'].dropna()
df['pub_rec_bankruptcies'].dropna()
```

Однако, после этого ситуация не меняется, хотя и ошибки тоже никакой не выдается.

Comment: dropna видимо создает копию объекта.

Comment: Потому что, как сказал @ВладиславХарламов, метод dropna создает копию объекта. Для того, чтобы у вас изменения вступили в силу , используйте `dropna(inplace=True)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Большинство методов в Pandas создают новый объект (видоизмененную копию) и возвращают этот новый объект, не изменяя при этом оригинальный объект (DataFrame, Series, etc.). Иногда можно воспользоваться параметром `inplace=True`, для того чтобы изменить исходный объект вместо того, чтобы возвращать новый. Но в английской версии SO мне как то попался комментарий одного из основных разработчиков Pandas (Jeff Reback), что он сам предпочитает не использовать параметром `inplace=True`, т.к. в глубинах имплементации нет гарантии, что изменения будут сделаны на оригинальном объекте. Вместо этого часто происходит неявное создание нового объекта и замена оригинального обхекта новым. К сожалению, я не смог найти этот комментарий...

Метод [DataFrame.dropna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) по умолчанию возвращает новый фрейм (видоизменённую копию), но не меняет исходный фрейм.

Попробуйте так:

```
res = df.dropna(subset=['pub_rec_bankruptcies', 'revol_util'])
```